# Ram disk for your OS that switches over after boot

Tags: boot, server, ram, disk

I just purchased a server for home use and want to use 20 of the 56Gb of ram that it has as a ram disk. Because it's relatively large, and Ubuntu Server ends up quite small, I was wondering if I could install my os to this ram drive. I know that ram is volatile, and all the data disappears when it looses power, but I'm wondering if there is a way that as soon as you turn on the server, it copies the ramdisk contents from some sort of backup file on my regular hard drive onto the ram disk, and then continues to boot from ram, giving my server superhuman R/W speeds. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://superuser.com/questions/389254/how-do-i-load-ubuntu-into-ram-and-boot-from-it) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1060176/how-to-get-ubuntu-system-to-boot-and-run-entirely-in-ram)?

Comment: Just did, Thanks. I essentially want to use the ideas in your second link, but I am ok with booting up my server, initializing the ram disk, copying over a drive image with Ubuntu installed, and then booting from that drive. I think my question is: Can I boot from a drive on my computer after it's already booted and make sure that my Ram's power isn't cut?